# how to pass value to second jsf page

Tags: jsf

If I use session scope for my managedbean then i can pass one variable value to all pages but 
If I use viewscope for my managedbean then my variable value is going to first page but not to second page. It means

**first page contains**

```
<p:inputText id="email" required="true"
                                    requiredMessage="Enter Email"
                                    value="#{loginController.empEmail}" >
                                </p:inputText>
<p:commandButton id="OTP" action="#{loginController.generateOTPForEmp}" 
                                rendered="#{loginController.loginAsEmp}" value="Generate OTP" update="@form">
                            </p:commandButton>
```

**managedbeans**

```
public String generateOTPForEmp() {
System.out.println(loginAsEmp);
}
```

**second page contains**

```
<p:inputText id="email" required="true"
                                        requiredMessage="Enter Email"
                                        value="#{loginController.empEmail}" >
                                    </p:inputText>
```

in second page "empEmail" not display

I need to pass that empEmail to second page also, 
What i need to do? (with viewscope)

Answer (score -1):

Define a bean for store user data in a session scoped, an a controller in view scoped, for process the view.

```
@Named("loginCtrl")
@ViewScoped
public class LoginController {

     @Inject private LoginData data;
     private long viewData;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
       setViewData(System.currentTimeMillis());
    }

    public String  doLogin(){
        return "index2.xhtml";
    }

    public String  goto3(){
        return "index3.xhtml";
    }

    public LoginData getData() {
        return data;
    }


    public void setData(LoginData data) {
        this.data = data;
    }


}
```

Then your data in sessionScope

```
@SessionScoped
public class LoginData implements Serializable{

    private String name;
// getters and setters
```

and then in view 1

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form id="form">
            <p><h:outputText value="new data #{loginCtrl.viewData}" /></p>             
            <p><h:inputText id="txName" value="#{loginCtrl.data.name}" /></p>
            <p><h:commandButton value="Login" action="#{loginCtrl.doLogin()}"></h:commandButton></p>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

in view 2

```
 <h:form id="form">
        <p><h:outputText value=" new data #{loginCtrl.viewData}" /></p>
            <p><h:outputText id="txName2" value="#{loginCtrl.data.name}" /></p>
            <p><h:commandButton value="Login" action="#{loginCtrl.goto3()}"></h:commandButton></p>

        </h:form>
```

and for example it's even valid in view 3

```
 <h:form id="form">
     <p><h:outputText value="new data #{loginCtrl.viewData}" /></p>             
     <p><h:outputText id="txName2" value="#{loginCtrl.data.name}" /></p>
</h:form>
```

in "viewData" you can check that every time you change the view you have a new instance of bean, but with the same session data.

Answer (score -1):

That is not possible with `@ViewScoped`, you need to use `@CustomScoped` to achieve this. (I assume you are not willing to use `@SessionScoped`)

[Here](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ManagedBeanScopes) is a nice article about this.